# google maps api v3 polyline default options?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on A Web app which is using **GOOGLE MAPS API v3**.

I am drawing a `poly-line` which connects with `Google Way Points poly-line`.

I want my poly-line to be of the same color and weight as that of `Way Points poly-line`.

But I am not able to figure out **what is the color code and stroke weight** of that default Google way points Blue-greenish line?

Comment: Do you use `DirectionsRenderer` as in [Google Waypoints example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)?

Comment: yes i have used direction renderer!!

Comment: that blue line's color code and stroke weight?

Comment: I found the answer in their source code ([directions.js](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/12/directions.js)). The default options are: `{strokeColor:"#0080ff",strokeWeight:6,strokeOpacity:.55}` (if anyone else needs them)

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't find anywhere about default stroke options so, I played a bit myself, it is very close to defaults I think:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   polylineOptions: {
       strokeColor: '#0088FF',
       strokeWeight: 6,
       strokeOpacity: 0.6
   }
});
```

DEMO Fiddle with added above parameters into Google's example: **http://jsfiddle.net/z9hJd/**

- You can look at http://www.colorpicker.com/ to check colors and play with `strokeColor` yourself.